# writer.writerow( ) returns ONLY the last result

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to scrape data from LinkedIn and save it in CSV format but I only get the last result. How can I fix my code to get all the results to be saved?

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as file_output:
    headers = ['employee_field']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    
    
    employee_field = driver.find_elements("xpath", '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li')
    for e in employee_field:
        print(e.text)
    writer.writerow({headers[0]:e.text})
```

Thanks in advance

I was trying to pull the data of all contacts that have similar job titles working in the same organisation. But the code is saving the last entry in the csv file.

Comment: `writerow` isn't in the `for` loop so only runs once.